# SSL_connect() return 0 and SSL_get_error return SSL_ERROR_SSL

Tags: c++, openssl

I try to connect SSL using openssl, happen error. This is my code:

```
void OpenSSLConnect(SOCKET hSocket)
{
SSL_CTX*      m_ctx;
SSL *m_ssl;
SSL_library_init();
SSL_load_error_strings();
m_ctx = SSL_CTX_new (TLSv1_2_client_method());
if(m_ctx == NULL)
    return;
m_ssl = SSL_new (m_ctx);   
if(m_ssl == NULL)
    return;
int i = SSL_set_fd (m_ssl, (int)hSocket);
long mode = SSL_set_mode(m_ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
int res = 0;

res = SSL_connect(m_ssl);
int error = SSL_get_error(m_ssl, res);

    }

return;
}
```

Who can help me why error happen ?

Comment: Can you get an error description ?

Comment: SSL_connect return 0; and SSL_get_error return SSL_ERROR_SSL:
A non-recoverable, fatal error in the SSL library occurred, usually a protocol error. The OpenSSL error queue contains more information on the error. If this error occurs then no further I/O operations should be performed on the connection and SSL_shutdown() must not be called.

Comment: You must read from the OpenSSL error queue.

Comment: This is error quue: "error:140C5042:SSL routines:ssl_undefined_function:called a function you should not call". I do not understand this message

Comment: I edit may code SSL_CTX_new (TLSv1_server_method()); ---> SSL_CTX_new (TLSv1_2_client_method()); queue error is : SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number. Thing problem is "TLSv1_server_method" then I change with other method but I still not working

Comment: Hi, Am also facing the same issue.. COuld you please let me know how to print the error queue?

Answer (score 0):

Just change  'TLSv1_server_method' to  'TLSv1_method'.

Comment: Check your private and public key on both side(client & server).

Answer (score 0):

The problem from create and connect socket. I using port blocked by server. After change port, It working. Thanks all